# multiple line charts with independent data Javascript (Chart.js or google-vizualisation)

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, chart.js

js and I have two datasets:

data1 = [[0,1],[2,3],[5,7]] and data2 = [[1,4],[2,6],[5,2],[7,1]] for example. 
Each data list contains lists that represent points to plot on a **same** chart. (x and y values)

I want to plot exactely like this : 
https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/line/multi-axis.html

But as you can see, my data lists don't have the same x or y values and they don't even have the same size, so I can't use the regular:

```
data: {labels = [1,2,3,4,5],
       data = [7,8,3,1,2],
       data = [9,1,2,3,4]}  //for example
```

How can I code this chart only with javascript (no jQuery please) ? I didn't find anything on the Internet that might help.
Any suggestions would matter to me !

Comment: What do you need that's not found in [that example](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/master/samples/charts/line/multi-axis.html)?

Comment: The thing is, both lines depend on the same x axis (months). But do you think I can swap the 24th line and the 25th line so both lines have their own 'labels'  on x_axis ? 
[link](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/2851a94b9206a37a238f91a8d364f75df17d4d14/samples/charts/line/multi-axis.html#L24-L26)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [scatter chart](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/scatter.html), that accepts the `data` as an array of objects containing `x` and `y` properties. To turn it into a line chart, define `showLine: true` inside the `data` configuration objects.

Given your data structures, the following line of code produces the data structure expected by Chart.js.

```
data1.map(o => ({ x: o[0], y: o[1] }))
```

Please have a look at below runnable code snippet.

```js
const data1 = [[0,1],[2,3],[5,7]];
const data2 = [[1,4],[2,6],[5,2],[7,1]]; 

new Chart('line-chart', {
  type: "scatter",
  responsive: true,
  data: {
    datasets: [
      {
        data: data1.map(o => ({ x: o[0], y: o[1] })),
        label: 'Dataset 1',
        showLine: true,
        fill: false,
        borderColor: 'red'
      },
      {
        data: data2.map(o => ({ x: o[0], y: o[1] })),
        label: 'Dataset 2',
        showLine: true,
        fill: false,
        borderColor: 'blue'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="line-chart" height="80"></canvas>
```

Comment: You are absolutely right, that's what I found out Yesterday. Thank you very much for your help.